# changing dimensions of a chart generated

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts, alignment

The following code is used to generate a barchart using the fusioncharts javascript library! All though the chart appears it is too small and aligned to the top left corner of the screen! How can increase the height and align the graph to the center of the screen?

```
<?php

require_once("includes/db.php");

require("src/fusioncharts.php");


?>


<!-- You need to include the following JS file to render the chart.
When you make your own charts, make sure that the path to this JS file is correct.
Else, you will get JavaScript errors. -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>

<?php

    // Form the SQL query that returns the top 10 most populous countries
    $sql = "Select count(Email) as Number,Date from reportorder GROUP BY date";

    // Execute the query, or else return the error message.
    $result =mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    // If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON string
    if ($result) {
        // The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data
        $arrData = array(
            "chart" => array(
              "caption" => "Online orders on daily basis",
              "paletteColors" => "#0075c2",
              "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
              "borderAlpha"=> "50",
              "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
              "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
              "plotBorderAlpha"=> "10",
              "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
               "xAxisName"=> "Date",
              "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
              "showValues" => "0",
              "divlineColor" => "#999999",
              "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
              "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0",
               "yAxisName"=> "Number of online orders"
            )
        );

        $arrData["data"] = array();

// Push the data into the array
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($arrData["data"], array(
            "label" => $row["Date"],
            "value" => $row["Number"]
            )
        );
        }

        /*JSON Encode the data to retrieve the string containing the JSON representation of the data in the array. */

        $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

/*Create an object for the column chart using the FusionCharts PHP class constructor. Syntax for the constructor is ` FusionCharts("type of chart", "unique chart id", width of the chart, height of the chart, "div id to render the chart", "data format", "data source")`. Because we are using JSON data to render the chart, the data format will be `json`. The variable `$jsonEncodeData` holds all the JSON data for the chart, and will be passed as the value for the data source parameter of the constructor.*/

        $columnChart = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myFirstChart" , 600, 300, "chart-1", "json", $jsonEncodedData);

        // Render the chart
        $columnChart->render();

        // Close the database connection
        $db->close();
    }

?>
```

Comment: can you provide the html code after the chart generated ? please use chrome and press F12 to get the html, if you do not know how to get the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, for the alignment use css, for the div where the chart is rendering.

```
  <?php

    include("fusioncharts.php");
    $hostdb = "localhost";  // MySQl host
    $userdb = "root";  // MySQL username
    $passdb = "";  // MySQL password
    $namedb = "mscombi2d";  // MySQL database name
    $dbhandle = new mysqli($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb, $namedb);
    if ($dbhandle->connect_error) {
      exit("There was an error with your connection: ".$dbhandle->connect_error);
    }


    ?>

    <html>
       <head>
        <title>FusionCharts XT - Column 2D Chart - Data from a database</title>


        <!-- You need to include the following JS file to render the chart.
        When you make your own charts, make sure that the path to this JS file is correct.
        Else, you will get JavaScript errors. -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
          #chart-1{
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
          }
        </style>
      </head>

      <body>
        <?php

        // Form the SQL query that returns the top 10 most populous countries
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT category, value1 FROM mscombi2ddata";

        // Execute the query, or else return the error message.
        $result = $dbhandle->query($sql) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");

        // If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON string
        if ($result) {
            // The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data
            $arrData = array(
                "chart" => array(
                  "caption" => "Online orders on daily basis",
                  "paletteColors" => "#0075c2",
                  "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
                  "borderAlpha"=> "50",
                  "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
                  "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
                  "plotBorderAlpha"=> "10",
                  "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
                   "xAxisName"=> "Date",
                  "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
                  "showValues" => "0",
                  "divlineColor" => "#999999",
                  "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
                  "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0",
                   "yAxisName"=> "Number of online orders"
                )
            );

            $arrData["data"] = array();

      // Push the data into the array
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          array_push($arrData["data"], array(
              "label" => $row["category"],
              "value" => $row["value1"]
              )
          );
          }

          /*JSON Encode the data to retrieve the string containing the JSON representation of the data in the array. */

          $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

      /*Create an object for the column chart using the FusionCharts PHP class constructor. Syntax for the constructor is ` FusionCharts("type of chart", "unique chart id", width of the chart, height of the chart, "div id to render the chart", "data format", "data source")`. Because we are using JSON data to render the chart, the data format will be `json`. The variable `$jsonEncodeData` holds all the JSON data for the chart, and will be passed as the value for the data source parameter of the constructor.*/

          $columnChart = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myFirstChart" , 600, 300, "chart-1", "json", $jsonEncodedData);

          // Render the chart
          $columnChart->render();

          // Close the database connection
          $dbhandle->close();
        }

      ?>

        <div id="chart-1">Fusion Charts will render here</div>

       </body>

    </html>
```